# Is there a difference between PRF and a hash function?

Tags: hash, pseudo-random-function

Is there a difference between  PRF and a hash function?

For example: Creation of a secret key is using PRF and creating a secret key is using hash function.

Comment: You should not be using a PRF to create secret keys. You should be using an RNG or CSPRNG, which *may* be built out of a PRG.

Comment: In the first phase of IKE protocol, the pseudo-random function is used to generate the secret keys.

Answer (score 11):

No, the two primitives are definitely not the same.

A pseudorandom function is a keyed function that is (computationally) indistinguishable from a function chosen at random from all functions with matching domain and range as long as the key remains secret.

On the other hand, a cryptographic hash function is a function with either a publicly known key (in theory) or no key at all (in practice) that is compressing and collision resistant. That means, it maps long inputs to outputs of a fixed length and it is hard to find two inputs that map to the same output.

Comment: i thought hash functions resemble to a random oracle (in theory), why would they have a public key in theory?

Comment: No, hash functions are only modeled as random oracles for proofs in the random oracle model. If we work in the standard model, a hash function is only assumed to be collision resistant. The key of a hash function stems from a technicality of defining collision resistance. The problem is that it is (almost) impossible to define collision resistance for a single function. Therefore collision resistance is defined for a function family, and the key is required to select a member of that family.